# Dimension of the space of cubic polynomials over $\mathbb{P}^5$ which vanish on the Veronese surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

How should one go about computing the dimension of the space of cubic polynomials over $\mathbb{P}^5$ which vanish on $\mathbb{P}^2$, where $\mathbb{P}^2$ sits inside $\mathbb{P}^5$ via [Veronese embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronese_surface). (Here $\mathbb{P}^k$ is complex projective space). I am more interested in elementary approaches.

Comment: It should be easy to find references stating the polynomials generating the ideal of the image here. These will be quadratic. It seems to me that you then just need to multiply these by all linear forms and see what you get.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\PP}{{\mathbb P}}$
$\newcommand{\Ohol}{{\mathcal O}}$
$\newcommand{\QQ}{{\mathbb Q}}$
$\newcommand{\sheaf}[1]{{\mathcal #1}}$

You can do the following calculation with Macaulay2. The idea is the following: One considers the sequence

$$0 \to \sheaf{I} \to \Ohol_{\PP^5} \to v_*\Ohol_{\PP^2} \to 0$$

where $v:\PP^2 \to \PP^5$ is the Veronese-imbedding. One applies $\bigoplus_d\Gamma(\PP^5,- \otimes \Ohol_{\PP^5}(d))$ and gets

$$0 \to I \to S \to R$$

with $S=\QQ[t_0,\ldots,t_5]$ and $R=\QQ[x,y,z]$ where $v:S \to R$ is given by
$t_0 \mapsto x^2,\ldots,t_5 \mapsto z^2$.

Now the vanishing cubic polynomials are $I_3 = \Gamma(\PP^5,\sheaf{I}(3))$ which can be selected by the command basis(3,id1) where id1 is the ideal $I$ in Macaulay2 (line i13 below). One counts $28$ columns in the result matrix, which is therefore the dimension of the space of cubic polynomials vanishing on the veronese-surface. To double check, one computes basis(3,S/id1) (line i15), which gives $28$ too. As the cubic polynomials have dimension $\binom{5 + 3}{3} = 56$, our calculation must be right.

```
i1 : R=QQ[x,y,z]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : S=QQ[t_0..t_5]

o2 = S

o2 : PolynomialRing

i3 : describe S

o3 = QQ[t , t , t , t , t , t , Degrees => {6:1}, Heft => {1}, MonomialOrder =>
         0   1   2   3   4   5                                                 

     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     {MonomialSize => 32}, DegreeRank => 1]
     {GRevLex => {6:1}  }
     {Position => Up    }

i5 : basis(2,R)

o5 = | x2 xy xz y2 yz z2 |

             1       6
o5 : Matrix R  <--- R

i6 : vmat = oo

o6 = | x2 xy xz y2 yz z2 |

             1       6
o6 : Matrix R  <--- R

i7 : phi=map(R,S,vmat)

               2             2        2
o7 = map(R,S,{x , x*y, x*z, y , y*z, z })

o7 : RingMap R <--- S


i12 : ker phi

              2                                    2                       2
o12 = ideal (t  - t t , t t  - t t , t t  - t t , t  - t t , t t  - t t , t  - t t )
              4    3 5   2 4    1 5   2 3    1 4   2    0 5   1 2    0 4   1    0 3

o12 : Ideal of S

i13 : basis(3, ker phi)

o13 = {2} | t_3 t_4 t_5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
      {2} | 0   0   0   t_3 t_4 t_5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
      {2} | 0   0   0   0   0   0   t_2 t_3 t_4 t_5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
      {2} | 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   t_0 t_1 t_2 t_3 t_4 t_5 0   0   0   0   0   0  
      {2} | 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   t_0 t_1 t_2 t_3 t_4 t_5
      {2} | 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      0   0   0   0   0   0   |
      0   0   0   0   0   0   |
      0   0   0   0   0   0   |
      0   0   0   0   0   0   |
      0   0   0   0   0   0   |
      t_0 t_1 t_2 t_3 t_4 t_5 |

o13 : Matrix

i14 : S1=S/(ker phi)

o14 = S1

o14 : QuotientRing

i15 : basis(3,S1)

o15 = | t_0^3 t_0^2t_1 t_0^2t_2 t_0^2t_3 t_0^2t_4 t_0^2t_5 t_0t_1t_3 t_0t_1t_4 t_0t_1t_5 t_0t_2t_5
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      t_0t_3^2 t_0t_3t_4 t_0t_3t_5 t_0t_4t_5 t_0t_5^2 t_1t_3^2 t_1t_3t_4 t_1t_3t_5 t_1t_4t_5
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      t_1t_5^2 t_2t_5^2 t_3^3 t_3^2t_4 t_3^2t_5 t_3t_4t_5 t_3t_5^2 t_4t_5^2 t_5^3 |

               1        28
o15 : Matrix S1  <--- S1
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this stuff, can you tell me the reference where I can find the algorithm that has been used here.